# Cast object in a call with performSelectorOnMainThread iOS

Tags: ios, performselector

If I use

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadDidEnd:) withObject:foo
        waitUntilDone:YES]
```

In the method -(void)uploadDidEnd:(id)sender

Which object is sender? in the call foo is a custom class? How can I convert this sender in my object?

I'm trying to cast but I'm having

```
'-[_NSThreadPerformInfo CountY]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x52bbd0'
```

In notifications, I use a cast from sender to NSNotification and notification have the object property, but for NSThread I didn't found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadDidEnd:)
      withObject:foo
      waitUntilDone:YES]
```

as sort of the same as:

```
[self uploadDidEnd:foo];
```

Are you sure that's what you're trying to do?

If so: inside your `uploadDidEnd:` implementation, you can cast foo to whatever object type it really is like so:

```
- (void)uploadDidEnd:(id)sender
{
  FooClass *foo = (FooClass *)sender;
  [foo doSomething]; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The argument declared a `sender` is the only parameter passed to your method. performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: passes its argument after `withObject` to the selector to be performed, so yes, here `foo` will be passed to uploadDidEnd:
2. Casting is not a solution. Objective-C is a dynamic language, so even if casting eliminates compiler warnings, the actual implementation of the object wouldn't change, so it naturally would not repond to messages.

Comment: But how I can take the passed object foo in called method?

Comment: How do you want to "take" it? It's right there in the argument.